# FlashDevelop crash on debugging Haxe Flash

Tags: flash, haxe, flashdevelop

FlashDevelop was working fine. Then one day, it started to crash everytime I debug Haxe Flash. Building/Compiling is fine. I've also tried to reinstall FD but it won't work.

Comment: Everything in this world, a millisecond before planting, it worked well ! Try to verify why it's crashing , surely you (or your OS, ...) have changed something that it doesn't like (SDKs, Flash Player, plugins, ...) !

Comment: Well, I did 'lime setup android' a few hours before before it started to crash.

Comment: So you did something ;) Try to rollback what you did, clean your development environment, and re-install FlashDevelop, and this time verify any requirement before installing anything.

Comment: Installing android tools through `lime setup android` could be the problem. I deleted everything and installed them again. At first, debugging worked just fine. After `lime setup android` and a restart, FlashDevelop crashed again. I used to setup android tools before and it didn't cause FD to crash. Weird... Anyway to fix this?

Comment: Seems like android tools are not the problem causing FD to crash. Installing FlashDevelop, haxelibs and a restart will cause FD to crash on debugging.

Comment: It works well again now. Anything I've said before could be right or wrong. Hope it will never crash again.